# Laravel image won't show up

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Code:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$company->logo) }}" alt="Image not available">
```

Element in inspection:

```
<img src="http://administration/storage/9db9e15d9f1f3d892cdcb595e2089dbf.jpg" alt="Image not available">
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edknl.png)

I'm doing a practice Laravel project and when I start getting the images from the database it just won't show up

I used the command php artisan storage:link so that images reach the public folder. Also, i created the images with faker. I'm using homestead and my application name is administration and also the URL is "http://administration".

Possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you save the image? I mean the path

Comment: it looks like the image is not saved in a public folder. You will either have to work with links or make a request to your backend to get the image.

Comment: If you saved your image on `storage/app/public` then make a symbolic link as `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: did you try `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: I checked for that but it exists in the public folder. How I get the image is by getting the name and extension of it from the database and then append them to the path and then make the whole path as my HTML image source.

Comment: In public folder, on which directory hold the image?

Comment: I did try it - Jitesh Dhamaniya

Comment: storage is the directory inside public that has my images

Comment: What you get on direct access `https://administration/storage/9db9e15d9f1f3d892cdcb595e2089dbf.jpg`

Comment: What is your current root url?  `https://administration` only?

Comment: 404 | Not Found && Yes it's just http://administration

Comment: I figured it out, turns out the problem was with homestead hosting. Thanks guys.